# OCR code through multiple files loop in R

Tags: r, ocr, tesseract

I want to run my OCR code for all the pdf's that I saved in my working directory. All these pdf's are downloaded with names as given by Report_{district name} where district name is a vector that I created. I want to convert the OCR output into a tibble, save the seperate tibbles for each pdf file.

```
url <- "https://tnsec.tn.nic.in/tnsec_upload/results/rlbe2019/vpp_{district_fcode}.pdf"
(urls <- glue(url))
pdf_names <- glue("report_{district_eng}.pdf")
walk2(urls, pdf_names, download.file, mode = "wb")
 data_files = list.files(pattern = 'pdf$')


n_files = length(data_files)
results <- integer(n_files)

list_files<-list.files()

lapply(list_files, function(x){
  out_tibble<-pdf_ocr_data(x, dpi = 600,language = "tam")%>%  str_split(pattern = "\n")%>%
    unlist() %>%tibble(data = .)
  out_tibble$source_file <- basename(x) # add a column with the excel file name
    return(out_tibble)
})
```

This is for a project that I am working on and I have been able to find no resources to help me here. I am new to R as well as Stack overflow, so pardon me if my question is unclear

When I tried the code separately for a particular pdf, OCR happened line by line, since my table was rather complex, with two lines in a cell, it would also be helpful if you can help me with that.

```
ocr_text <- pdftools::pdf_ocr_data('vpp_ari.pdf', dpi = 600,language = "tam")


raw_tibble <- a %>%

  str_split(pattern = "\n")%>%

  unlist() %>%

  tibble(data = .)
```